# My android studio project is not giving me the option to build apk. How can I fix it?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to build my project in android studio but the option to build apk is not showing up.

Comment: You problem has been fixed or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File > Project Structure then add modules fix it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried checking your project structure has an Android facet? Look under

**File > Project Structure > Project Settings > Facets**

I'm not sure why this is happening, but as a workaround, you could use gradle build tasks.

I generally do all this from the command line. If you don't have any build flavors, try doing the following:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Or maybe just try **Sync project with Gradle Files** option under Files.

Answer (score 0):

Vist in your module's iml file `root/main_module/main_module.iml`and remove that line.

`<excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/apk" />`

When you remove that line then, the build options will show at.

`root/main_module/build/apk/` in the file tree